# How to use an existing Mac app via command line?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, command-line, terminal

I am looking to adapt a css formatter app I downloaded from the app store so I can control it from the command line. Basically before I push a file to github I would like to have the app format a .css file. So I am wondering How I would get the app to run its process without doing it by hand.

I am not sure where to begin... I have xcode.

So my question is, where do I begin?

Can you point me to any articles of people that have done something similar?
What files should I be most concerned with in the app?

Thanks for the direction

Comment: You can run apps from the command line by executing them as any normal executable...

Comment: What do you mean by "hack" and why would you need Xcode? Just start the executable.

Comment: I am trying get the app to run its process and format a css file with out ever leaving terminal. This way before I push it to github I can have the app format the file first.

Comment: I don't see why this has been closed. It is a real question.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a regular app from the Mac App Store, you can find the executable in the app bundle at `Contents/MacOS/AppName`.

So to start the Mail app for instance you would have to execute this:

```
/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want to just start it from the command line, you want to make it do something useful.

### 1 - Disassemble and link your own program

A Mac app will have an executable (in TheApp.app/Contents/MacOS/APP_NAME) in the bundle (which is just a directory). Xcode won't really be all that much help.

The app will most likely use AppKit / NSApp Cocoa framework and the executable will create an App instance, set up the GUI etc, register things. Cocoa apps work on a system of delegates, callbacks, etc. It's not just one main function that runs synchronously. They almost certainly won't export simple external symbols that you can link against and call. And even if you did, you'd need the header files.

You could look into an Objective-C disassembler, as the compiled executable probably has enough symbols to work out roughly what's going on. But you'd need to know a fair bit about Objective-C and Cocoa (at least, enough to know that this will be tough).

So Option 1, which isn't really an option in unless you know what you're doing, is work out what the program symbols are / disassemble the executable, and write your own application that links against the binaries and calls the relevant methods.

### 2 - Script the GUI

On another tack, you could look into whether it's Apple-scriptable. You could start the app, record activity (look at the AppleScript editor's record functionality) to script the actual GUI. This might work.

### 3 - Talk to the author

I suggest you talk to the author if you really want this. Perhaps they can make it usable as a command line tool.